# 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium

How to fix this error `'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

```
Davao14 = wd1.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]')
Davao15 = wd1.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')
Davao16 = wd1.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]')
Davao17 = wd1.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]')
Davao18 = wd1.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]')
Davao19 = wd1.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[6]')
Davao20 = wd1.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[7]')
Davao21 = wd1.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[8]')

Cebu14 = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]')
Cebu15 = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')
Cebu16 = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]')
Cebu17 = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]')
Cebu18 = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]')
Cebu19 = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[6]')
Cebu20 = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[7]')
Cebu21 = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[8]')

Manila14 = wd3.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]')
Manila15 = wd3.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')
Manila16 = wd3.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]')
Manila17 = wd3.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]')
Manila18 = wd3.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]')
Manila19 = wd3.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[6]')
Manila20 = wd3.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[7]')
Manila21 = wd3.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[8]')
```

```
data1 = [Davao14, Davao15, Davao16, Davao17, Davao18, Davao19, Davao20, Davao21]
data2 = [Cebu14, Cebu15, Cebu16, Cebu17, Cebu18, Cebu19, Cebu20, Cebu21]
data3 = [Manila14, Manila15, Manila16, Manila17, Manila18, Manila19, Manila20, Manila21]

for datas1 in data1:
  for datas2 in data2:
    for datas3 in data3:
      print("***DAVAO-CITY***\n\n")
      print(datas1.text)
      print("\n\n")
      print("***CEBU-CITY***\n\n")
      print(datas2.text)
      print("\n\n")
      print("***MANILA-CITY***\n\n")
      print(datas3.text)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
***DAVAO-CITY***


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-63ba9131bde0> in <module>()
      7     for datas3 in data3:
      8       print("***DAVAO-CITY***\n\n")
----> 9       print(datas1.text)
     10       print("\n\n")
     11       print("***CEBU-CITY***\n\n")

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: You are trying to find `Davao14` with `wd1.find_elements`. Using **elements** returns a list. And the you are adding it to `data1` , now `data1` is a **list of list**. In the `for loop` `datas1` is a list and you cannot extract Text from a list.

Comment: `find_elements` returns a list, 

change `elements` to `element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data1 = [Davao14, Davao15, Davao16, Davao17, Davao18, Davao19, Davao20, Davao21]
```

data1 is a list of list of web elements. what it means is, `Davao14` is also a list. same for Davao15 and so on..

```
for datas1 in data1:
    for inside_list in datas1:
        print("***DAVAO-CITY***\n\n")
        print(inside_list.text)
```

You can similarly have different loops for `data2` and `data3`

**Update :**

Nested loops are one way to quickly get a `big O notation`.

Typically (but not always) one loop nested in another will cause `O(n²)`.

I would not prefer nested loop for this use case..

```
for datas2 in data2:
        for inside_list in datas2:
            print("***DAVAO-CITY***\n\n")
            print(inside_list.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`datas1` is a list of strings while each `data1` element is a string.
The same about the `datas2` & `data2` and `datas3` & `data3`.
String element has no `.text` method.
List of string also has no `.text` method.
To print the all the lists of strings you should pass strings themselves directly to the `print()` method.
So instead of

```
data1 = [Davao14, Davao15, Davao16, Davao17, Davao18, Davao19, Davao20, Davao21]
data2 = [Cebu14, Cebu15, Cebu16, Cebu17, Cebu18, Cebu19, Cebu20, Cebu21]
data3 = [Manila14, Manila15, Manila16, Manila17, Manila18, Manila19, Manila20, Manila21]

for datas1 in data1:
  for datas2 in data2:
    for datas3 in data3:
      print("***DAVAO-CITY***\n\n")
      print(datas1.text)
      print("\n\n")
      print("***CEBU-CITY***\n\n")
      print(datas2.text)
      print("\n\n")
      print("***MANILA-CITY***\n\n")
      print(datas3.text)
```

It should be

```
data1 = [Davao14, Davao15, Davao16, Davao17, Davao18, Davao19, Davao20, Davao21]
data2 = [Cebu14, Cebu15, Cebu16, Cebu17, Cebu18, Cebu19, Cebu20, Cebu21]
data3 = [Manila14, Manila15, Manila16, Manila17, Manila18, Manila19, Manila20, Manila21]

for datas1 in data1:
  for datas2 in data2:
    for datas3 in data3:
      print("***DAVAO-CITY***\n\n")
      print(data1)
      print("\n\n")
      print("***CEBU-CITY***\n\n")
      print(data2)
      print("\n\n")
      print("***MANILA-CITY***\n\n")
      print(data3)
```